# What's the word for a number which is used to scale down a value?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

I'm a programmer and I'm creating an API in which there is a parameter the user can pass in which scales down a value. So for example:

```
FinalValue = SOME_CONSTANT / scaleDownValue
```

I guess it could be called a scalar or maybe some kind of weight? Anyway, I'm sure there is a better mathematical term for this value other than "scaleDownValue" =)

Comment: I would call it a scalar and I would also multiply it by SOME_CONSTANT rather than divide. If I wanted to shrink SOME_CONSTANT I would just make the scalar a number between $0$ and $1$. But I'm sure it depends on what you're trying to do and how the overall code will read.

Comment: I would call it ScalingFactor.  This word combines the scaling property that is the goal, with the multiplication that is the mechanism.    I concur with @ToddWilcox that multiplication is more natural than division; then you don't need to worry if it's zero.

Comment: @vadim123 that's nice. Thank you!